# Does mixing genders in an army lead to a lower incidence of sexual abuse by male soldiers?

Tags: gender, military, israel

The Israeli Knesset member [Merav Michaeli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merav_Michaeli) has uploaded a [video](https://www.facebook.com/MichaeliMerav/videos/1346402548716781/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED) to her Facebook page where she claims:

> אני רוצה לדבר על זה שאילו מתחילת הקריירה הצבאית שלו היו ליד אופק בוכריס חיילות לוחמות, וקצינות שעלו איתו בסולם הדרגות [...] היה הרבה פחות סיכוי שהוא היה בועל בעילה אסורה חיילת שצעירה ממנו בעשרים שנה. ככה מוכיח בפירוש הנסיון בצבא האמריקאי ובצבאות אחרים  שבהם התחילו להתגבר על האפליה.

This translates roughly into:

> I want to talk about that that if from the start of his career Ofek Buchris was next to combatant female soldiers and officers who rose through the ranks with him, [...] there was a smaller chance that he would have screwed a soldier that is 20 years younger than him. This is clearly proven by the experience of the US military and other military forces that started to overcome discrimination.

Does mixing genders in an army lead to a lower incidence of sexual abuse by male soldiers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50678/discussion-between-ilya-melamed-and-oddthinking).

Comment: Relevant: http://www.nytimes.com/2004/02/26/us/military-women-reporting-rapes-by-us-soldiers.html?_r=0

Comment: Relevant: http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2010/12/2010122182546344551.html